# How do I filter based on multiple criteria in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I currently have a set of events which I would like to filter based on its timing: past or upcoming, as well as its type: hackathon, workshop, or field trip. The timing filter is controlled with buttons and the type filter is controlled with a dropdown of checkboxes. Currently, the filter function only applies the most recently selected criteria, but I want it to work when multiple criteria are selected as well. How do I filter based on multiple conditions, for example to search for events which are past hackathons as opposed to just past events or just hackathons? My code is below.

HTML:

```
     <div style="margin-left: 25%; display: flex; justify-content: center">
        <!-- Control buttons -->
        <div id="myBtnContainer" style="justify-content: center; display: flex; margin-bottom: 40px">
            <button class="btn active left-btn" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('upcoming')">Upcoming</button>
            <button class="btn right-btn" onclick="filterSelection('past')">Past</button>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 10%">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" style="background-color: white"
                id="sampleDropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Type
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu filters" style="top: 50%">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "event-check" value="fieldtrip" 
                    onClick="filterSelection('field-trip')"> Field Trip
                </button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "event-check" value="hackathon"
                    onClick="filterSelection('hackathon')"> Hackathon
                </button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "event-check" value="workshop"
                    onClick="filterSelection('workshop')"> Workshop
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The div for an event-card looks like:

```
    <div class="event-card upcoming hackathon">
```

JS:

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("event-card");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) x[i].classList.add("show");
  }
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[1].className = current[1].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem more ?
in filterSelection function you are getting event-card class element but in side html not any tag have that class

Comment: Just an aside but your `w3Add/RemoveClass` functions are totally outdated. Replace `w3AddClass(x[i], "show")` with `x[i].classList.add("show")` and bring your code out of last millennium :)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I am trying to apply multiple filters to my set of data but at the moment my filterSelection function only allows one. How can I edit it to filter across multiple criteria based on which are selected via the buttons and dropdown?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol haha I grabbed the code from w3schools but thank you for the edit :)

Comment: okay i think function is correct you just have to check your html ,
the tags which have event-card class also have  hackathon , workshop or field-trip etc class because it check on the basis of class name

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I edited the post to show a div containing the event-cards. The method for selecting the time of the event (buttons) is separate from that for selecting the type of event (dropdown-checkbox), so the criteria are not selected all at once. At the moment, the filter is only applying the most recently selected criteria, i.e. only one class, but I want it to filter based on all the selected ones.